# SelectedIndexChanged event dont fire when create a dropdownlist in code-behind

Tags: asp.net

For two day i try to solve this issue.

I create a dropDownList in code-behind, in selectIndexChange of another dropDownList, and add this new dropDownList to page using a placerHolder, everthing its ok, but new dropdownlist selectIndexChange event dont fire!

code of dropDownList creation

```
dropDown = new DropDownList();
dropDown.AutoPostBack = true;
dropDown.ID = idSubistema;
dropDown.Width = 400;
dropDown.CssClass = "controltext";
dropDown.DataValueField = "IDNivel";
dropDown.DataTextField = "NIVEL";
dropDown.EnableViewState = true;
dropDown.DataSource = 
   DBLibray.DefinitionIndicadores.spSelect_FillCombosWithNivelByIdParent(
       ref dataConnector, 
       Convert.ToInt32(idSubistema));

dropDown.DataBind();

dropDown.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(indexChange);
//dropDown.PreRender += new EventHandler(dropDown_PreRender);

placeHolderForCombos.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>"));
placeHolderForCombos.Controls.Add(lb);
placeHolderForCombos.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
placeHolderForCombos.Controls.Add(dropDown);
placeHolderForCombos.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
placeHolderForCombos.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
```

Can't anybody help with this??

Thanks

Comment: Profile it through firebug and see whether changing the selectedItem in DropDownList fires any javascript event?

Comment: In which method does this code appear (e.g. PageInit)? Is there a reason you're not using the declarative markup?

Comment: @Graham, he answers this in his question: "I create a dropDownList in code-behind, in selectIndexChange of another dropDownList" He has a DropDownList which is in the markup and raises SelectedIndexChanged and in the event handler method for this event he creates a second DropDownList. So the code is in the method someDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making things really hard for yourself by creating controls in this way. Although ASP.Net WebForms pretends to work like WinForms by raising events and such, it isn't. HTTP is a stateless protocol. Therefore, *every time* a user requests an ASPX page, *every postback*, the entire page needs to be re-constructed by ASP.Net.

There is a [page lifecycle](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_events.aspx) that gets run through (init, load, pre-render, etc), and if a control is not created in this lifecycle, it won't exist, and won't be rendered to the client. By creating controls "dynamically" in the way that you're doing, you need to make sure they get created at the right time, *every time* the page is loaded. This method also makes dealing with Viewstate a little more tricky, and it's a pain anyway.

You might have a really complicated page that makes creating controls like this absolutely necessary, but it's more likely that you'll be better off writing your second drop-down list in the ASPX markup in the normal way. This will ensure it's always available to use. You can then conditionally databind to it, and toggle its `Visible` property. If this property is `false`, the control won't be rendered to the client at all.

In general with ASP.Net, if you're creating controls in this way, it's a sign that you're over complicating matters. Not always the case, but more often than not.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new dropdown in event "selectIndexChange". it's too late. Try to create dropdown in Page_Load or databinding event. use visibility to show/hide your ddl "idSubistema"